# How to construct a Relative Frequency Table in Minitab

Tags: statistics, minitab

I am struggling to construct a relative frequency table for the following data in MiniTab. I have followed all the directions given to me but cannot construct the right table. Can anyone please provide me the steps.

The data:

```
Rino Species | Population Estimate
----------------------------------
African Black | 3590
African White | 11350
Sumatran      | 600
Javan.        | 30
Indian        | 2100

Total  17670
```

I am still learning MiniTab so not sure how to do this and generate a relative frequency table from this data. Can anyone help me here?

I expecting the to get count and percentage through Minitab but not been able to figure out how. The steps I follow does not do the job for me.

I tried Minitab > Stat > Tables > Tally individual variables > Select 'Population estimate' as my variable and display count and percents. It does not generate the right data.

Answer (score 0):

Hey this is pretty old but what you can do is go to Stat>Tables>Cross Tabulation and Chi-Square. Once in that window select Raw Data in the first drop down, then in rows put your categorical column C1, then in frequency put in count column C2. Select total percents on the check box. Then click OK and it should display a chart with total relative percentages.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).